# Add a heavily nested dictioary to MongoDB preserving its format

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I pulled some data from the Facebook GraphAPI using python and saved it to a variable. The API returns JSON which is saved as a nested dictionary in Python. This is what the data from the API looks like in the browser.

[image]

Python dict looks like this :
[image]

I want mongoDB to store the data in the sane JSON format as returned by the FB API. Is that possible ?

Code :

```
import facebook

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='my_token', version='2.7')

post = graph.get_object(id='me/friends', fields='feed{message,story,story_tags,created_time,id,message_tags},posts{message,story,story_tags,message_tags,created_time,id},name')
print(post)
```

Any help please.

Answer (score -2):

Yes:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient().test
db.collection.insert_one(post)
```

[The PyMongo tutorial](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) is a good way to learn Python and MongoDB.

Comment: Doesn't work Jesse. I am aware of the insert_one() function. It does not add it in the way like the JSON from the API. I want the data in MongoDB to look exactly like data from the API in the first image.